# Decimal point KeyPress event on Samsung Galaxy S5 not firing?

Tags: javascript, android, input, keypress

First off, why does the decimal point appear on a numeric keypad - only on the S5? I don't want it to appear. Second, and most importantly, I can't even disable the decimal entry by observing the keypress event, because "." does not seem to fire one on S5 with 4.4.2

```
<input type="number" placeholder="YYYY" name="year" class="char-4" inputmode="numeric" pattern="[0-9]*" data-numeric-input="" maxlength="4" max="9999">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fv3dfeu3/2/

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using the default Samsung keyboard?

Comment: The default Samsung keyboard will always show the decimal point for the numerical keyboard, even if you set the input not to accept decimal points. This is the behaviour of the Samsung keyboard and there is nothing you can do about it.

Since your input does not accept decimal point, the keypress will not be fired, so nothing will happen when you press it.

Comment: @desmondtzq what do you mean "since your input does not accept decimal point"? It's not supposed to accept it...but it does :)